# How to prevent BleachBit from resetting file associations

Tags: bleachbit

After I run *BleachBit*, the file associations for PDF, EPUB, JPG and PNG are reset to the system's defaults (I'm using Windows, so the defaults are Microsoft Edge or Windows Image Viewer).

I don't know which option to tick off in order to prevent *BleachBit* from resetting file associations. I cannot find any information about this in the software or online.

Any idea?

---

My guess would be that the option is among these:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one? Please let me know how it goes

```
[Cached File Extensions *]                                                      
LangSecRef=3025                                                                 
Detect=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows                                          
Warning=This possibly will reset default programs back to default on Windows 8/8.1.
RegKey1=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts        
RegKey2=HKU\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts
```